# Attributes having different case behaving strangely

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa, lombok

I have an JSON which has an entity. This entity has 3 attributes: 
`firstName`, `FirstName`, `fIRStName`. In my POJO, I am using `@Data` annotation from Lombok

```
{
      "name": "AtQueryEntity",
      "attributes": [
        {
          "name": "FirstName",
          "type": "STRING",
          "required": true
        },
        {
          "name": "fIRStName",
          "type": "STRING",
          "required": true
        },
        {
          "name": "FIRSTName",
          "type": "STRING",
          "required": true
        }
      ]
}
```

The problem is that MYSQL, creates only 2 columns.

1. `Id`
2. `FIRSTName`

How to ensure that columns are created for all the attributes?

I know that the convention is that attributes should be unique and first alphabet of an attribute should be lowercase but I have a usecase wherein attributes can be different only by Upper or Lower case.

Is there a limitation in Hibernate or JPA wherein it doesn't create column for attributes which differ only by Upper or small case? Or I am missing something here?

Comment: In MySQL, ["Column, index, stored routine, and event names are not case sensitive on any platform, nor are column aliases."](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html) So you'll have to explicitly declare the unique (case-insensitive) column names to use for each field.

Comment: Thanks. I would need to add a validation to disallow attribute names having same frequency of alphabets

Answer (score 0):

> I have a usecase wherein attributes can be different only by Upper or Lower case.

**fOrGeT iT!** There's `ImplicitNamingStrategy` and `PhysicalNamingStrategy` in Hibernate, which may or not be supported with JPA2, and MySQL supports quoted names, so you might be able to get it work somehow.

At the same time, you can be sure, you'll soon run into a tool not supporting it at all. Using names differing only in case is a big pain, it'll surely surprise you many times, be it with Java Beans or Windows or whatever.

The Java Beans conversion between field and getter/setter names is not bijective, so you'll run into problem. Lombok is or isn't fully Java Beans conform, depending on how you understand this stupid standard (`java.beans` itself is internally inconsistent w.r.t. the casing).

And no, *there's no use case* for this. While you may be given such data from  a third party, this doesn't imply you should code *your program* using them. Such names are pain for the tools and also for the programmer. Just sanitize your inputs ASAP and de-sanitize the output ALAP.

Even `_1` and `_2` are better identifiers than `FirstName` and `fIRStName`, so avoiding the latter can't ever go wrong.

> Thanks. I would need to add a validation to disallow attribute names having same frequency of alphabets.

This has nothing to do with the column names. This means you need a column named like `column_name` where you store strings like `"FirstName"`, `"fIRStName"` and `"FIRSTName"`. That's no problem at all.